# presentViewController doesn't present

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uistoryboard, presentviewcontroller

i made a single view project with storyboard, added a couple of viewcontrollers. 
the initial viewcontroller has a simple button to display another viewcontroller

```
- (IBAction)doPhotoAlbumBtn:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main.storyboard" 
                                                         bundle:nil];
    VCDecorations *ieVC = 
     [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VCDecorations"];
    [self presentViewController:ieVC animated:NO completion:nil];
 }
```

I imported the class, connected the biecontroller in the ib to the right class, have on the viewcontroller the right identifier and checked the "use storyboard ID" checkbox
and i feel like im missing smth very basic.
help me guys.
Thanks.

Comment: Try [self storyboard] instead of UIStoryboard.

Comment: Did you set the `Storyboard ID` value to VCDecorations above the chekbox?

Comment: You Can use segue while using storyboard.In that case do segue then you give it identifier and you can do segue from one controller to second using prepareforSegue method.

Comment: no i cant use segues because i use the photo selection modal and then present the viewcontroler. i couldnt manage doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to switch to a `UIViewController` inside the same storyboard as the current `UIViewController` is in you can do that with this:

```
UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ID"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

**EDIT**

To pass data you use a block in `completion:block`, add a property for the object you want to pass things to. The block executes when the animation is done.

Comment: thank you, it worked.
BUT..
It seems not the right way, im trying to pass data forward and i cant (tried changing the label text of the presented vc)

Comment: I did answer your question and it was successful,please check it as the right answer.